# Having Trouble Normalizing Posterior Distribution in Python

Tags: python, bayesian

I am coding the derivation of a Dirichlet-Multinomial posterior in a paper that I've read and I am having trouble getting the distribution to sum to 1. Here is the code in its unsimplified form:

```
def pcn(X, n, N, c, alpha):
    pnc = np.math.factorial(np.sum([n[i] for i in range(len(n))]))/ \
          np.product([np.math.factorial(n[i]) for i in range(len(n))])* \
          np.product([c[i]**n[i] for i in range(len(n))])
    pc = G(len(X)*alpha)/ \
         np.product([G(alpha) for i in range(len(n)) if i in X])* \
         np.product([(c[i])**(alpha - 1) for i in range(len(n)) if i in X])
    pn = np.math.factorial(N)/ \
         np.product([np.math.factorial(n[i]) for i in range(len(n)) if i in X])* \
         G(len(X)*alpha)/ \
         G(len(X)*alpha + N)* \
         np.product([G(alpha + n[i])/G(alpha) for i in range(len(n)) if i in X])
    return pnc
```

which I've simplified here removing the parts that get divided out:

```
def pcns(X, n, N, c, alpha):
    pnc = np.product([c[i]**n[i] for i in range(len(n))])

    pc = np.product([(c[i])**(alpha - 1) for i in range(len(n))])/ \
         np.product([G(alpha) for i in range(len(n))])

    pn = np.product([G(alpha + n[i])/G(alpha) for i in range(len(n))])/ \
         G(len(X)*alpha + N)

    return pnc * pc / pn
```

I set the input variables and initialize the array of c to input:

```
X = [0,1]
n = [6.0, 3.0]
N = sum(n)
alpha = 20
c = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
```

and then I iterate over c and evaluate my posterior function at each c and plot:

```
dist = []
for i in c:
    dist.append(pcns(X, n, N, [i, 1-i], alpha))

plt.plot(c,dist)
```

[image: click here to see the posterior plot]

The value I get when I sum over `dist` is 999 or `len(c) - 1`. Would anyone happen to know why it doesn't some to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: you're computing a discrete approximation to a definite integral and forgot to multiply the pieces by dx ~= delta_x.

---

Even if this were a correctly normalized probability distribution, why should `dist` *sum* to 1?  Since we don't have `G` I can't reproduce exactly your results, so let's consider a simple Gaussian instead.  We can set the mean to 0.5 and the stddev to something small, so that the range from 0 to 1 should contain most of the probability:

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> c = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
>>> p = scipy.stats.norm(0.5,0.02).pdf(c)
>>> sum(p)
999.00000000000045
```

And there's that 999 again.  But again, why *should* this be 1?  The quantity which should be one is the total integrated *probability*.  Here we're just taking values of the probability distribution function at some points and adding them together.

Easier example: we know the definite integral of x^2 from 0 to 1 is 1/3, but

```
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
>>> sum(x**2)
333.50016683350009
```

when really we want something more like (crude rectangular approximation, a little above the desired answer because we're including a contribution from the x=1 point and that box is actually out of the integral region):

```
>>> sum(x**2) * (x[1]-x[0])
0.3338340008343344
```

Or in your previous situation

```
>>> sum(p) * (c[1]-c[0])
1.0000000000000004
```

Note that here we can write `* (c[1]-c[0])` because `c` is equally-spaced and so every "dx" in `Int(p(x) dx) ~= sum(p[x] * delta_x)` is the same.  In general we'd want something more like `sum(p[:-1] * np.diff(c))`.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the informative answer. The G function, by the way, is the Gamma function. Sorry i wrote this while very sleepy.